# How to make make an Mpdf compatible document?

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, mpdf

I am trying to use the overwrite feature of Mpdf, as many have found only documents created or using "the same encryption" can be modified using Mpdf.

Is there a way to make my current PDF, Mpdf compatible, either saving as a different format or running through Mpdf?

This is my code, it is working but obviously only for pdf's made using Mpdf

```php
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

$mpdf->OverWrite('test.pdf', '%%NAME%%', 'CHRIS', 'F', 'new_test.pdf') ;
?>
```

Comment: There is no such thing. PDF is the document format, which is the standard. Mpdf is just a library that uses it...

Comment: So why would mpdf only be able to edit documents pre made by it in the past and not others?